# Can I do type inference in Java? Yes I can

Tags: java, generics

I am an experienced C++ developer learning Java abstract concepts.

I was looking if I can do type inference in java and the answer is usually no and that I need to pass the Class type when calling a generic function. like so:

```
<T> void test(T t, Class<T> clazz);
```

I though this is redundant and that the compiler should be able to infer the type (C++ does it why can't Java :p) but then when I understood how generics are implemented under the hood I realized that `T` is essentially `Object` at runtime.

But then I realized that I can still call `Object` member functions on an instance of `T`. So I'm able to do something like this:

```
<T> void test(T t) {
    if (t.getClass() == Integer.class ) {
        // T is of type Integer.
    }
}
```

1- Is there an advantage of either techniques over the other (i.e. passing `Class<T>` over checking Class type using `getClass`)?

2- Is there anything wrong with the second approach? The reason I am asking is that I have seen people go to the extend of using reflection and some obscure techniques before following what I've written above. Ideas?

Comment: `t.getClass()` can return a subclass of `T`. Also not all scenarios will have an instance of `T` as an input parameter.

Comment: Or it could raise a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `if (t.getClass() == new Integer(1).getClass() ) {` could also be written `if (t.getClass() == Integer.class) {`; this only works if you know all the types you want to check. There is also [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) which is available for *reflection*.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Good point will edit post as this is not the core of the question.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues here:

- In general, you shouldn't really be inspecting the types of things at runtime. It's not *wrong*, per se, but if you feel the need to do it, then you're probably taking the wrong approach. For generics, for example, the whole point of a generic method is that it works *regardless* of the type argument.

  - Unlike C++, Java doesn't have any concept of template specialization; and Java programmers are comfortable with this restriction. Idiomatic Java code does not try to circumvent it.
- There's no guarantee that `t.getClass()` is the same as the type `T`; `t` could be an instance of a subtype of `T`, for example. (Whereas a `Class<T>` is guaranteed to be the type `T`, unless it's null, or unless the program has "polluted the heap" by circumventing the generic type system.)

If you're going to do this, I'd suggest writing `if (t instanceof Integer)` instead of doing anything with `getClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything wrong in the above approach?

Absolutely! If you have to "unmask" the generic type parameter `T` to do something special, you might as well do it in a separate piece of code, and either pass it on the side the way the class is passed, or require `T` implement a specific interface that provides the "special" functionality.

> Is there an advantage of either techniques above over the other (i.e. passing `Class<T>` over checking Class type using `getClass`)?

Passing `Class<T>` technique has a specific reason behind it - letting you construct objects when you have none to begin with. In other words, it is applicable when you have no object on which to call `getClass()`, but you want to return an instance of `T` instead.